# How can I make the Outlook 2007 inbox mail subject titles with bigger fonts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

My Outlook inbox mail subject title listing is so small that I need to use a magnifying glass to see/read them. I am using Outlook 2007.

I can set the side panel mail items bigger. but not the email subject listings.

I have Asus N56VJ i7 with 1080P full HD screen. If I set to lower resolution like 1300 X 600, the listing will appear bigger. But this will affect my other applications.

Anyone know how to set the display font for Outlook 2007 inbox?

Do I need to buy the new Microsoft Office 2015?

Answer (score 1):

#### How to change subjects’ font size in mail list of Outlook?

> 1. Open the mail folder.
> 2. Set the view to "Compact":
>
>    - Outlook 2010 and 2013, click "Change View" > "Compact" on the "View" tab.
>    - Outlook 2007, click "View" > "Current View" > "Messages".
> 3. Change the view settings of current mail folder:
>
>    - Outlook 2010 and 2013, click the "View Settings" button on the "View" tab.
>    - Outlook 2007, click "View" > "Current View" > "Customize current view".
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the "Advanced View Settings: Compact" dialog, click the "Other Settings" button.
>
>    [image]
> 5. In the "Other Settings" dialog box, click the "Row Font" button.
>
>    [image]
> 6. In the "Font" dialog box, choose a font size and click the "OK" button.
>
>    [image]
> 7. Click the other "OK" buttons to exit all dialog boxes.

Source [How to change subjects’ font size in mail list of Outlook?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1887-outlook-subject-line-font-size.html)